# Spark java dataframe String cannot be converted to struct

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below spark schema defined

```
        StructType state = DataTypes.createStructType(
                new StructField[] {
                        DataTypes.createStructField("version", DataTypes.IntegerType, false),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("value", DataTypes.StringType, false)
                        });

        ArrayType relationship = DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.createStructType(
                new StructField[] {
                        DataTypes.createStructField("cid", DataTypes.StringType, false),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("state", state, false),
                        }));

        StructType cr = DataTypes.createStructType(
                new StructField[] {
                        DataTypes.createStructField("cmg", relationship, false)
                });

        StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(
            new StructField[] {
                    DataTypes.createStructField("cr", cr, false)
            });
```

If I create the dataframe as

```
Row r1 = RowFactory.create("{cr:{cmg:[{cid:\"B06XW5BXJZ\",state:{version:19,value:"approved"}}]}}");
List<Row> rowList = ImmutableList.of(r1);
Dataset<Row> df = spark.sqlContext().createDataFrame(rowList, schema);
```

The code gives below error

```
The value ({cr:{cmg:[{cid:"B06XW5BXJZ",state:{version:19,value:"approved"}}]}}) of the type (java.lang.String) cannot be converted to struct<cmg:array<struct<cid:string,state:struct<version:int,value:string>>>>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute `createDataFrame(rowList, schema)` Spark tries to interpret the content of each element in `rowList` using the provided schema.
However, the values in `rowList` are strings, and not structured objects, so Spark is unable to apply the schema.

You have various options to load that object into a dataframe in structured form.

##### Load the data as json string and use spark to parse it

```
String jsonRow = "{cr:{cmg:[{cid:\"B06XW5BXJZ\",state:{version:19,value:\"approved\"}}]}}";
Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataset(List.of(jsonRow), Encoders.STRING())
            .select(functions.from_json(functions.col("value"), schema, Map.of("allowUnquotedFieldNames", "true")));
```

in this case it first creates a `Dataset<String>` in which each row contains a single String column (`value`) and then uses the [`from_json`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#from_json-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.util.Map-) spark sql function to parse the json using your schema.

Also note the use of the `allowUnquotedFieldNames=true` option, required because in the input string the field names are not quoted.

##### Manually create structured rows and load them in a Dataframe

```
Row structuredRow = RowFactory.create(RowFactory.create(List.of(RowFactory.create("B06XW5BXJZ", RowFactory.create(19, "approved")))));
Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(List.of(structuredRow), schema);
```

This extends your initial attempt to use the `RowFactory` to manually create the rows. The rows must reflect the structure defined in the schema (or rather, the schema must respect the structure of the rows).

##### Use a custom Java bean class

###### Class definitions

```
public static class State implements Serializable {
    private Integer version;
    private String value;
    // getters, setters, constructors
}

public static class Relationship implements Serializable {
    private String cid;
    private State state;
    // getters, setters, constructors
}

public static class Cr implements Serializable {
    private List<Relationship> cmg;
    // getters, setters, constructors
}

public static class RowBean implements Serializable {
    private Cr cr;
    // getters, setters, constructors
}
```

###### Use the bean class to create a Dataset

```
RowBean row = new RowBean(new Cr(List.of(new Relationship("B06XW5BXJZ", new State(19, "approved")))));
Dataset<RowBean> ds = spark.createDataset(List.of(row), Encoders.bean(RowBean.class));
```

In this case, using a custom Java bean / Scala case class, the schema is extracted directly from the class structure using `Encoders.bean()`

Comment: I went with the `Manually create structured rows and load them in a Dataframe` and it works great for me